# How can I change the Windows 10 default monospace font?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, fonts

I don't like Courier New/Consolas (the default monospace on Windows 10) due to it being hard to read and bad for programming.

I tried changing the registry key of the font that I wanted to replace to an already installed font (JetBrains Mono): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`. However it changed the default monospaced font to Arial.

How can I change the windows 10 default monospace font so every program and website use it when they specify that they want to use a monospace font (without specify any font name. ie: `monospace`)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`, value `Courier New CE,238` with the font that you want. Example: `Arial` If I want to use arial.

Comment: This didn't worked out. The font didn't showed up.

Comment: I believe you have to either restart explorer.exe (not the file manager, but the shell) or restart the computer